# .htaccess. redirecting urls that has a "go" tag

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having a pretty hard time on .htaccess URL rewrites in PHP. I want to put a specific condition to it but it has not worked out yet.

I WANT TO WRITE A CONDITION TO REDIRECT EVERYTHING THAT HAS A "GO" IN ITS URL

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*&go=([^?&]*)\??([^&]*)&*.*$
```

Redirect /alice1.html http://www.google.com'
 ***the failed condition that i tried***

FOR AN EXAMPLE IF SOMEBODY TYPES

> 'localhost/alice1.html' IT SHOULD NOT BE REDIRECTED TO google.com

BUT IF IT IS

> 'localhost//alice1.html?go=www.something_something.com'

THEN IT SHOULD BE REDIRECTED.

Comment: Hi there. I've removed the please-do-it-for-me part of your question, as those sorts of questions are not encouraged here. It's great you have an attempt - try adding mod_rewrite logging to see where it is going wrong, maybe? Secondly, please don't shout in your questions - ordinary sentence case is much better. Lastly, questions need formatting here, to make them readable - see my edit.

Comment: accept my deepest apologies over the lapses... i will make sure that i would not repeat such errors in the future... thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can start from this base rule.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bgo=.+
RewriteRule . http://google.com? [L]
```

Then refine the checking of the `go` variable.

**edit**: note that this is just a template rule matching your input. On a production server it would be better to either set it as an external redirection (using `[R=301, L]` instead of just `[L]`, assuming you want it permanent) or switch to an appropriate error page (403, 404...)